# SQLite adding a numerical var to existing value in js

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I have the following table

```
buildingcode buildingreceiptno buildingaddress buildingpay
1012         2                 address 1       0
1001         3                 address 2       0
1003         0                 address 3       0
```

I want to update buildingreceipt of a certain buildingcode by a numerical var

I use the following code but it does not work

```
t.executeSql('UPDATE buildings SET buildingpay = ?, buildingreceiptno = buildingreceiptno + numericalValue WHERE buildingaddress = ?', 
     [myrow.payamount.toFixed(2), myrow.buildingaddress]);
```

myrow.payamount.toFixed(2), myrow.buildingaddress are correct vars

Answer (score 0):

You could improve it, but this should be a working solution for your problem:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {

  // Get buildingreceiptno value
  tx.executeSql(
    "SELECT buildingreceiptno FROM buildings  WHERE buildingaddress = ?", 
    [myrow.buildingaddress], 
    function(tx, res) {
        var buildingreceiptno = res.rows.item(0).buildingreceiptno;
        tx.executeSql(
            "UPDATE buildings SET buildingpay = ?, buildingreceiptno = ? WHERE buildingaddress = ?",
            [myrow.payamount.toFixed(2), buildingreceiptno + numericalValue, myrow.buildingaddress], 
            function(tx, res) { console.log(tx, res); }, 
            function(tx, err) { console.log('ERROR: ', tx, err); }
        );
    }, 
    function(tx, err) { console.log('ERROR: ', tx, err); }); 
  });
```

Always use error callbacks to print out errors, it helps a lot.